# Совместимость библиотек между языками

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Какие языки программирования имеют совместимость с библиотеками C++? Я имею в виду возможность подключения скомпилированных статических библиотек C++, к проектам на других языках.

Comment: Опишите подробнее о какого рода совместимости Вы хотите узнать.

Comment: Рекомендую ознакомится со статьёй «Руководство новичка по эксплуатации компоновщика» (https://habrahabr.ru/post/150327/). В ней подробно объясняется, что представляют собой статические библиотеки, а также как они связываются и используются. Обладая этой информацией, можно будет узнать, имеет ли тот или иной язык и его среда разработки необходимые для использования статических библиотек возможности.

Comment: чтобы сделать библиотеку c++ совместимой с чем-нибудь внешним, обычно делают C-интерфейс, впрочем да, лучше статью прочитайте